# NEMA17 Stepper motor not turning, but making very little noise

Tags: raspberry-pi, stepper-motor, l298

I have a NEMA17 stepper motor (2 Phase, Rated 12V, 1.2A/Phase) and I am trying to make it run with an L298N and a Raspberry Pi. Everything is wired up as shown below in the pictures. I use a 12V, 2A power supply to power the L298N. The RPi is powered separately.

I measured the resistance between the different stepper motor leads. I have been told that two wires are a pair if they have very little resistance. If there is no resistance, they are not a pair. This way, I think The correct pairs are in the A and B terminals of the L298N.

I'm using the following python script:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# Variables

delay = 0.05
steps = 50

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

# Init pins

coil_A_1_pin = 9
coil_A_2_pin = 25
coil_B_1_pin = 11
coil_B_2_pin = 8

# Set pin states

GPIO.setup(coil_A_1_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(coil_A_2_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(coil_B_1_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(coil_B_2_pin, GPIO.OUT)

# Function for step sequence

def setStep(w1, w2, w3, w4):
  GPIO.output(coil_A_1_pin, w1)
  GPIO.output(coil_A_2_pin, w2)
  GPIO.output(coil_B_1_pin, w3)
  GPIO.output(coil_B_2_pin, w4)


# Example rotations: forward and backward

for i in range(0, steps):
    setStep(1,0,1,0)
    time.sleep(delay)
    setStep(0,1,1,0)
    time.sleep(delay)
    setStep(0,1,0,1)
    time.sleep(delay)
    setStep(1,0,0,1)
    time.sleep(delay)

for i in range(0, steps):
    setStep(1,0,0,1)
    time.sleep(delay)
    setStep(0,1,0,1)
    time.sleep(delay)
    setStep(0,1,1,0)
    time.sleep(delay)
    setStep(1,0,1,0)
    time.sleep(delay)
```

The stepper motor does not move whatsoever, unfortunately. It does make very little noise when running the script.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this project are very welcome.

More details on the stepper motor:
PHASE : 2 PHASE
STEP ANGLE : 1.8 ± 5% ° /STEP
VOLTAGE : 12V 
CURRENT : 1.2 A/PHASE 
RESISTANCE : 10.0 ± 10% ?/PHASE 
INDUCTANCE : 20 ± 20% mH/PHASE 
HOLDING TORQUE : 48 N.cm Min 
NUMBER OF LEADS : 4 
LEAD STYLE : AWG26 UL1007 
LEAD STYLE : AWG26 UL1007 
ROTOR TORQUE : 68 g.cm2 
INSULATION CLASS : B 
SIZE : 41 x 41 x 62mm 
WEIGHT : 181 grams

[image: schematic]

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

[image: pic3]

[image: pic4]

Comment: And your schematic is....

Comment: Welcome, jvermeulen! as Tyler correctly indicates, a good question also includes a clear schematic of what you're doing – that's what the built-in schematic editor is for.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: A schematic has been added above. I hope it is clearer now!

Comment: That is not a schematic, but it might be enough.

Comment: @jvermeulen: that's really everything but a schematic (that's why I referred to the built-in schematic editor... *sigh*), but it certainly helps.

Comment: No, it doesn't really help. What is the designations of the clamps on the controller board? Really, draw a properly annotated real schematic.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The motor controller board is a standard L298N module I bought. I'm quite new to this. I don't think i could draw a schematic of the module, unfortunately. I'm very sorry! Is there any other information that could be useful that you're lacking, in order to understand what is happening?

Comment: The clamps on the controller board are just jumpers shorting the enable pins for motor A and B. Documentation online says to leave it in place when using a stepper motor and to remove it when powering a DC motor using PWM.

Comment: I might have found something useful. If I measure the input voltage to the input terminals on the L298N, it measures 12V. However, if pin 1 is set to 0, pin 2 to 1 and the others to 0, then it measures almost no voltage at the motor A terminals. In this case, the H bridge should let current flow through motor A, not through motor B. Weird that the voltage drops almost 12V... Any idea how this might occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the "reputation" to comment.....but, are the grounds (12-volt ground and Raspberry Pi ground) connected together?  They must be!

Comment: That was it! Thanks!
I wonder, why is that necessary? Won't the current flow to the ground of the L298N instead of back to the raspberry pi?

Comment: Current flows in a loop.  A small current coming out of the Raspberry Pi must return somehow.  The 12-volt supply is isolated from the AC socket that it is plugged into.  Same for whatever is powering your Raspberry Pi.  You must have a connection between the grounds.

Comment: But, when touching an electric fence, current does flow to your body through another ground, thus not circular. Why does current flow in that case, compared to this case?

Comment: Any large conductive body can be considered to be a ground.

Comment: For example, planet earth.  If you are still confused by all of this, consider starting a new question....we are getting off topic.